# How to pass Edit Text Value to a function

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm trying to make a simple function that tests the strength of a password.
The password is entered into an edit box, then the function is called which returns a score of its strength.
I'm not sure how to pass the value from the edit box to the function, since the value is Unicode String.

This is the first part of the function

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) calculateStrength(const wchar_t* 
password){

bool hasUpper = false;
bool hasLower = false;
bool hasDigit = false;
bool hasSymbol = false;

int PassScore = 50;

for(int i = 1; i <= sizeof(password); ++i)
{
    if( islower(password[i]) )
        hasLower = true;
.....
```

And here is where I call it

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender){
const wchar_t* password = EnterPass->Text.t_str();

int PassScore = calculateStrength(password);
....
```

I'm really new to all of this, and this is based on hours of Googling.
When I input just one letter and put just `ShowMessage(wcslen(password))` the output is 50, for more then one character it's 75, etc.
I presume I'm not converting types right, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question, but your loop over the string will go past the end of the array. Unless you're using some kind of 1-indexed operator[].

Comment: `sizeof(password)` is `sizeof(wchar_t*)`, and thus either 4 or 8 (32 bit or 64 bit platform). It is not the length of the password. Also note that by the time you are using the *pointer* password, the *string* may have already been freed and the memory be re-used. Rather pass: `calculateStrength(EnterPass->Text.t_str())` directly. That could also explain the weird result for the `ShowMessage` (which expects a string, BTW).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Don't use `t_str()` at all.  Use `c_str()`, `w_str()`, or even `data()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wcslen()` instead of `sizeof()`, 
like this:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) calculateStrength(const wchar_t* password)
{
    bool hasUpper = false;
    bool hasLower = false;
    bool hasDigit = false;
    bool hasSymbol = false;

    int PassScore = 50;

    int len = wcslen(password);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (islower(password[i]))
            hasLower = true;
        ...
    }

    return PassScore;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString password = EnterPass->Text;
    int PassScore = calculateStrength(password.c_str());

    // or simply:
    // int PassScore = calculateStrength(EnterPass->Text.c_str());

    ...
}
```